# MDC values not passed to requests

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, slf4j, logback

I want to have a separate log file for each application while using just one `logback.xml` file. Therefore I'm using a [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/access/sift/SiftingAppender.html).

Every application has it's own [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) that assigns a specific [MDC](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html).

When I start my Tomcat server all the log files are split as they should.

But when I send a request to the server the logging output gets written to the *unknown* file. Obviously the MDC value can't be read.

As far as I know MDC values are copied from the parent thread to the child thread. Where is each request's thread created so I can assign the MDC value there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although classic servlet containers like Tomcat use a *Thread-Per-Request* model, you **cannot** rely on any mapping of a single thread to a single web-application. This is because requests are serviced from a pool of **container-managed** threads, e.g. imagine a thread pool with 3 threads A, B and C. These service requests, which alternate between two webapps W1 and W2 in a round robin fashion:

```
request 1 on W1 serviced by A
request 2 on W2 serviced by B
request 3 on W1 serviced by C
request 4 on W2 serviced by A
...
```

As you can see, Thread A first handled a request to webapp W1 and was later reused for a request to webapp W2. Therefore you cannot assign a web-app id to a thread once and be done with it. Instead, on every single request, you have to

- set the web-app id in the threads MDC before processing the request
- remove the web-app id from the request thread after processing is complete

Both of these tasks can for example be fulfilled by a [Servlet Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). The [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) also explains this in the section *"MDC and Managed Threads"*. There is even a [sample filter implementation](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/helpers/MDCInsertingServletFilter.html) available, which you can modify to fit your needs.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073019/how-to-use-mdc-with-thread-pools

Comment: The answer given there is applicable for situations where your program controls the creation of threads (or creation of the thread pools). Note that this is generally not the case for web applications.

Comment: I'm setting the MDC property in an incoming filter, and clear it in an outgoing filter, and I have a **single** web-app running on my Servlet Container (Tomcat).
Is it still safe to assume that each thread will only handle a single request at any given time?