# How to use MDC values set in request Filter with apache camel threadpool?

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel, logback, mdc

I am currently facing a problem where my logs are giving false information. The MDC values set for one request are getting logged with logs generated by other requests.

I understand that this problem is happening because I am using Parallel processing in camel in my scenario. Has anybody else encounter a similar problem and how was it solved?

This seems to be a common issue when using apache camel for processing web requests but I didn't see enough information regarding this on the web.

I will really appreciate any help in the regard. Thanks

Comment: I am looking at the same problem. I will post the solution if I work it out, but I believe you need to have a custom thread pool executor and somehow get it injected into the Camel Context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073019/how-to-use-mdc-with-thread-pools