# Using org.slf4j.MDC with Netty channels?

Tags: java, logging, netty, slf4j, logback

What I want to do is in essence what  [How to use MDC with thread pools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073019/how-to-use-mdc-with-thread-pools) is asking, but with Netty.

I want MDC information associated per `Channel`.  What options are there for Netty?  If I need to reset MDC manually, what methods can I hook up to do this from one place?