# Log4j2 ThreadContext map is not working for parallelStream()

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, log4j, log4j2

I have following sample code:

```
public class Test {
    static {
        System.setProperty("isThreadContextMapInheritable", "true");
    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadContext.put("UUID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        LOGGER.info("in main method start");
        new Test().run();
        LOGGER.info("in main method end");    
    }

    private void run() {
        Collections.nCopies(10, 1)
                .parallelStream()
                .forEach(i->LOGGER.info("Inside thread"));    
    }
}
```

Log4j2 pattern is following:

```
<pattern>%X{UUID} [%t] %msg %n</pattern>
```

Running above produce result:

```
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [main] in main method start 
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [main] Inside thread 
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [main] Inside thread 
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [main] Inside thread 
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [main] Inside thread 
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [main] Inside thread 
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] Inside thread 
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Inside thread 
 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Inside thread 
 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Inside thread 
 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] Inside thread 
2cf774ff-03c8-483e-9828-451b61349221 [main] in main method end
```

As you can see, the first time in `[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]` and `[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3]` threads `UUID` variable was logged, but other times were not logged.

Why Log4j2 skips `ThreadContext` variable for some threads and how to fix this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Only threads started by your thread may inherit values from your thread. Are you sure that all these entries show the name `ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1` and not `ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-some-other-number`?

Comment: Sample is completely working and result is just copy-pasted, without any modifications.

Comment: @Holger I have tried to run more times, and got different result. Just updted the question. So per mine understanding, ThreadContext only inherits values from [main] thread, and when ForkJoinPool creates forked thread, it is not created from [main]. So, is this possible to resolve such issue somehow?

Comment: It’s a well-known problem of inheritable thread locals and thread pools that you don’t have control over who creates a thread, as re-using already existing threads is the very purpose of thread pools. So you may inherit a value or not or may even inherit a wrong value. But what’s irritating, is that the log output suggests that the same thread appears to have the value in one log entry but not in the next.

Comment: @YaroslavBoichuk I have the same problem, did you find any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post,
But I struggled on the same problem and it took me few days to find a working solution.
Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329668/11825162), creating a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` did fix my problem.