# Log4j ThreadContext MultiThread won't inherit

Tags: java, log4j

I encounter this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675779/log4j2-threadcontext-map-is-not-working-for-parallelstream)'s problem
Here my sample of code

```java
public class StackOverflow implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, ApiGatewayResponse> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(StackOverflow.class);

    public abstract class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
        // Working Interceptor using this.print("message")
        public abstract void print(String line);
    }

    private class ErrStreamGobbler extends StreamGobbler {
        ErrStreamGobbler(InputStream in) { super(in); }

        @Override
        public void print(String line) { LOGGER.error(line); }
    }

    private class OutStreamGobbler extends StreamGobbler {
        OutStreamGobbler(InputStream in) { super(in); }

        @Override
        public void print(String line) { LOGGER.info(line); }
    }


    // MAIN METHOD
    @Override
    public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(Map<String, String> params, Context context) {
        // ThreadContext propagation
        System.setProperty("isThreadContextMapInheritable", "true");
        ThreadContext.put("foo", "bar");

        LOGGER.info("Hello from main");

        // My process will return value on System.in & System.out
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", String.format("batchs/JOB_FOO/run.sh"));
        Process p = pb.start();
        // Intercept those logs
        new ErrStreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream()).start();
        new OutStreamGobbler(p.getInputStream()).start();
        p.waitFor();
    }
}
```

The `ThreadContext` from `LOGGER.info("Hello from main");` does work and also prints `foo: bar`.
But my child threads `StreamGobbler` doesn't get `ThreadContext` and won't print `foo: bar` as a log4j property event if `isThreadContextMapInheritable` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered this problem.  Found setting -DisThreadContextMapInheritable=true at application startup works, even though setting it in the code does not.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` did fix my problem.
Found this solution using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329668/11825162).