# Spring Boot Filter not filtering all my logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, logback

I have a Filter set up in my Spring Boot app to add some information to the MDC:

```
@Component
public class LogFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig var1) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            MDC.put("tag", "Some information);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.clear();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

This works fine for most of my application, but for certain operations where a thread is spawned, this filter is not picking up those messages.

For example, in the block below, the callback methods occur in a separate thread, so the first `log.info` call is getting picked up by my `LogFilter`, but the `log.info` and `log.error` in my callbacks aren't.

```
private void publishMessage(String message) {
    log.info("Message received. Sending to Kafka topic");
    CompletableFuture<ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> kafkaTemplate.send("myTopic", message));

    try {
        future.get().addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                log.info("Kafka topic " + myTopic + " published to successfully");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                log.error("Kafka error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Kafka has failed you for the last time");
        }
    }
```

In general, it seems like any log event that doesn't occur in one of the `http-nio-8080-exec-X` threads bypasses `LogFilter`. What am I doing wrong?

Things I've tried that haven't worked:

1. Having `LogFilter` extend `GenericFilterBean`, use `@Bean` instead of `@Component`, and then registering that bean with `FilterRegistrationBean` in my main Application class
2. Using `@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"}, description = "MDC Filter")` and/or `@ServletComponentScan`

Answer (score 1):

MDC context is only available for the current running thread but your callback will be called within a different thread.

one way to deal with it is to implement `ListenableFutureCallback`:

```
private static class MyListenableFutureCallback
              implements ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>> {

            private Map<String,String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                MDC.setContextMap(contextMap); //add MDC context here
                log.info("Kafka topic " + myTopic + " published to successfully");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                MDC.setContextMap(contextMap); //add MDC context here
                log.error("Kafka error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

and finally:

```
future.get().addCallback(new MyListenableFutureCallback()).
```

a more consistant way of doing this is described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329668/10664446)

Comment: This would definitely fix my threads, but is there any way to get the MDC to be picked up by threads spawned by a library? For example, `kafkaTemplate.send()` will spawn threads and those log events won't contain `tag` either.

Comment: I'm not sure the other solution solves my issue as I'm not using `ThreadPoolExecutor`, nor am I understanding how to hook this up in a spring boot application

Comment: I don't know if only declaring your taskExecutor as @Bean is enough or not, are you using spring kafka?

Comment: Yeah we're using spring-kafka. In any case, modifying the MDC it seeming to be overkill given the information I'm trying to send is static. I think modifying our GELF appender in logback should be sufficient