# Spring Boot 3 TaskExecutor context propagation in micrometer tracing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, micrometer-tracing

Spring Boot 3 has changed context propagation in tracing.
https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide#async-instrumentation

They deliver now library to this issue. I guess I don't quite understand how it works.
I have created a taskExecutor as in guide.

```
@Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
            @Override
            protected ExecutorService initializeExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler rejectedExecutionHandler) {
                ExecutorService executorService = super.initializeExecutor(threadFactory, rejectedExecutionHandler);
                return ContextExecutorService.wrap(executorService, ContextSnapshot::captureAll);
            }
        };
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
```

And I have marked @Async like this:

```
 @Async("taskExecutor")
    public void run() {
        // invoke some service
    }
```

But context is not propagated to child context in taskExecutor thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can autowire your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and Context wrap in AsyncConfigurer.

```
import io.micrometer.context.ContextExecutorService;
import io.micrometer.context.ContextSnapshot;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AsyncTraceContextConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
  
  // NOTE: By design you can only have one AsyncConfigurer, thus only one executor pool is
  // configurable.
  @Qualifier("taskExecutor") // if you have more than one task executor pools
  private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

  @Override
  public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    return ContextExecutorService.wrap(
        taskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor(), ContextSnapshot::captureAll);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you have more than one executor pools and wants to add tracing to all, use the `TaskDecorator` with `ContextSnapshot.wrap()`:

```
import io.micrometer.context.ContextSnapshot;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import org.springframework.boot.task.TaskExecutorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskDecorator;

@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig {
  @Bean
  public TaskDecorator otelTaskDecorator() {
    return (runnable) -> ContextSnapshot.captureAll(new Object[0]).wrap(runnable);
  }

  @Bean("asyncExecutorPool1")
  public Executor asyncExecutorPool1(TaskDecorator otelTaskDecorator) {
    return new TaskExecutorBuilder()
        .corePoolSize(5)
        .maxPoolSize(10)
        .queueCapacity(10)
        .threadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor1-")
        .taskDecorator(otelTaskDecorator)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean("asyncExecutorPool2")
  public Executor asyncExecutorPool2(TaskDecorator otelTaskDecorator) {
    return new TaskExecutorBuilder()
        .corePoolSize(5)
        .maxPoolSize(10)
        .queueCapacity(10)
        .threadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor2-")
        .taskDecorator(otelTaskDecorator)
        .build();
  }
}
```

> NOTE: You can follow this [blog](https://medium.com/@amithkumarg/micrometer-tracing-in-spring-boot-context-propagation-for-async-scheduled-newspan-b80f4f4b2c9f) for more setup details and sample github project code.

Comment: Yes, I can do like this. But I need way to capture all my executors in application.

Comment: Updated my answer to suit your exact needs.

Comment: ContextSnapshot::captureAll is deprecated. ContextSnapshotFactory.builder().build().captureAll() should be used

Comment: I suppose `otelTaskDecorator` is a method call in `.taskDecorator(otelTaskDecorator)`? If yes, do we need to make that decorator a bean?

Comment: this method in the config above creates that bean: `public TaskDecorator otelTaskDecorator()`

Comment: Thanks Amith. But for some reason adding a task decorator as you've mentioned in solution 2 isn't working for me. I don't see the traceId being propagated. However, following https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329668/8283737 did help propagating the traceIds. What am I missing?

Comment: I have also written this [blog](https://amithkumarg.medium.com/micrometer-tracing-in-spring-boot-context-propagation-for-async-scheduled-newspan-b80f4f4b2c9f), check that out for more details and there is a link to Github sample project there too. May be compare your code to see what is missing. If nothing works out, share your sample code through github and I can take a peek to see what's missing.

Comment: @user2590727 can you share what works for you? i struggled with the acceptance answer with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Pls add this code to the configuration and everything works as expected.

```
  @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
  static class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer, WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
      return ContextExecutorService.wrap(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), ContextSnapshot::captureAll);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(r -> new Thread(ContextSnapshot.captureAll().wrap(r))));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but only for executors from autoconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, but I suspect it's a bug.

```java
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor(){
            @Override
            protected ExecutorService initializeExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler rejectedExecutionHandler) {
                ExecutorService executorService = super.initializeExecutor(threadFactory, rejectedExecutionHandler);
                return ContextExecutorService.wrap(executorService, ContextSnapshot::captureAll);
            }
            @Override
            public void execute(Runnable task) {
                super.execute(ContextSnapshot.captureAll().wrap(task));
            }

            @Override
            public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
                return super.submit(ContextSnapshot.captureAll().wrap(task));
            }

            @Override
            public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
                return super.submit(ContextSnapshot.captureAll().wrap(task));
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a bean ContextPropagatingTaskDecorator. It will be picked by the auto configuration and wired to ThreadPoolTaskExecutorBuilder.

See: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutorConfigurations.ThreadPoolTaskExecutorBuilderConfiguration#threadPoolTaskExecutorBuilder

```
   @Bean
   public TaskDecorator decorator(){
       return new ContextPropagatingTaskDecorator();
   }
```

That way you can use it in

```
   @Autowired
   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor scheduler;


   void test() {
        scheduler.submit(() -> log.info("Running task using scheduler "));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

ContextSnapshot::captureAll is deprecated.  This is the code that worked for me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Value("${setting.threads:2}")
    private int numOfThreads;

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return ContextExecutorService.wrap(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads), ContextSnapshotFactory.builder().build()::captureAll);
    }
}
```