# Spring Integration delay along with thread MDC context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, thread-local, mdc

I've a spring integration flow in which i have currently introduced a manual conditional delay by using Thread.sleep()

I understand that this is inefficient and would now like to refactor the whole flow using spring integrations native [delay support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/delayer.html)

However my current application is very much single threaded and as such there are a lot of monitoring/tracing libraries adding their context in the threadcontext/mdc

```
 IntegrationFlow.from("input")
            .handle((message, h) -> {
                // initial logic which may set thread context
            })
            .handle((message, h) -> {
            // conditional delay logic invoking Thread.delay()
            })
            .handle((message, h) -> {
            // subsequent logic which may rely on the thread context
            })
            .channel("output")
            .get();
```

The channel is being defined in this way

```
 @Bean(name = "input")
public MessageChannel getChannel() {
    DirectChannel dc = new DirectChannel();
    dc.setComponentName("input");
    dc.setDatatypes(ConsumerRecord.class);
    return dc;
}
```

Even the thread which is sending the message to this channel can set something in the mdc; this works because i'm using `DirectChannel` and per my understanding for `DirectChannel` the execution of the flow happens on the calling thread only.

Now will it work if i refactor this to something similar to the below code

```
    IntegrationFlow.from("input")
            .handle((message, h) -> {
                // initial logic which may set thread context
            })
            .delay(d -> {// some delay config})
            .handle((message, h) -> {
            // subsequent logic which may rely on the thread context
            })
            .channel("output")
            .get();
```

My hunch is that the context will get lost the moment the message goes into the delay channel and the next time whichever thread gets assigned to this task will not remember the context and as such my subsequent logic would fail.

What is the right way to achieve this in the world of spring-integration ??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. The `DelayHandler` uses a `TaskScheduler` to delay those messages via scheduled tasks. And it is not a surprise that thread locals are lost in a scheduled thread.

One of the simplest way to propagate that thread local context (MDC in your case) is to set it into a message header and then restore it back to thread local in the next step after delayer.

Another way is to implement a `TaskScheduler` facade similar to the `DelegatingSecurityContextTaskScheduler` and inject it into that `delay()` function.

**UPDATE**

Here is some idea how MDC propagation can be implemented: https://moelholm.com/blog/2017/07/24/spring-43-using-a-taskdecorator-to-copy-mdc-data-to-async-threads

It is discussed here: [How to use MDC with thread pools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073019/how-to-use-mdc-with-thread-pools)